# Elegant way to take multiple 2D slices of NumPy matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a very big 2D matrix:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.random.random((8000, 8000))
```

I have four very large arrays (around 5 million elements), all of which have the same shape, and they are`from_row`, `to_row`, `from_col`, `to_col`. These four arrays, as their name suggests, represent the coordinates of rectangles I want to crop from the `X` matrix. The resulting rectangles are guaranteed to all have the same size.

Basically, I want to do something like this in a more efficient way:

```py
n_rects = len(from_row)  # The four arrays have the same shape
crops = np.zeros((n_rects, rect_height, rect_width), dtype=X.dtype)
for i in range(n_rects):
    crop[i] = X[from_row[i]:to_row[i], from_col[i]:to_col[i]]
```

Is it possible to do such a thing more efficiently?

Comment: so the slices are all the same size?

Comment: Correct, all rectangles have the same size, so they can be stacked into a NumPy volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
Another, easier way would be to index a sliding window view of the array:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv
out = swv(X, (rect_height, rect_width))[from_row, from_col]
```

---

You can do this in a vectorized way by leveraging numpy's advanced indexing rules combined with broadcasting for convenience. Note that in order for this to work, each rectangle needs to have the same size, so it might be more natural to work with a `start` and `size` rather than a `start` and `end`. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

H, W = 10, 10
X = np.arange(H * W).reshape(H, W)

n_rects = 5
rect_height, rect_width = 4, 6

# Some random starting indices
from_row = np.random.randint(H - rect_height, size=n_rects)
from_col = np.random.randint(W - rect_width, size=n_rects)

# Numpy magic:
rows = from_row[:, None, None] + np.arange(rect_height)[None, :, None]
cols = from_col[:, None, None] + np.arange(rect_width)[None, None, :]
# Note that `rows` and `cols` broadcast to a
# shape `(n_rects, rect_height, rect_width)` array

# Now simply index:
out = X[rows, cols]
```

Results:

```
>>> from_row
array([5, 4, 3, 3, 4])
>>> from_col
array([2, 3, 1, 0, 1])
>>> out
array([[[52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57],
        [62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67],
        [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77],
        [82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87]],

       [[43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48],
        [53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58],
        [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68],
        [73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78]],

       [[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36],
        [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46],
        [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56],
        [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66]],

       [[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
        [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65]],

       [[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46],
        [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56],
        [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66],
        [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76]]])
```